# Setting the TOPCOLORS environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, top

I don't seem to be able to find any examples on the Internet for this environment variable, which `top` will apparently read and use to display colours.

How would I set this variable correctly so `top` used alternate colours in its output?

I have Solaris `top` version 3.5beta9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TOPCOLORS variable in this `top` (also referred to as [unixtop](http://www.unixtop.org/)) is not available in the version you are using.  It first appeared in version 3.6 of this utility, as stated in the COLOR section of the [README file](http://www.unixtop.org/readme.shtml).  For some reason, it seems that the usual BSD don't include an updated version of top (FreeBSD 9.1 has 3.5beta12).

If you can install or compile an updated version, the man page should give you more information on how to set colours.  In version 3.8beta1 that is what it prints:

---

### TOPCOLORS

Specifies colors to use and conditions for which they should be used.
At the present time, only numbers in the summary display area can be
colored. In a future version it will be possible to highlight numbers
in the process display area as well.  The environment variable is the
only way to specify color: there is no equivalent command line option.
Note that the environment variable **TOPCOLOURS** is also understood. The
British spelling takes precedence.  The use of color only works on
terminals that understand and process ANSI color escape sequences.

The environment variable is a sequence of color specifications, separated
by colons. Each specification takes the form `tag=min,max#code` where

- `tag` is the name of the value to check,
- `min` and `max` specify a range for the value, and
- `code` is an ANSI color code.

Multiple color codes can be listed and separated with semi-colons.  A missing `min` implies the lowest possible value (usually 0) and a missing `max` implies infinity. The comma must always be present.

When specifying numbers for load averages, they should be multiplied by 100.  For example, the specification:

- `1min=500,1000#31` indicates that a 1 minute load average between 5 and 10 should be displayed in red.

Color attributes can be combined.  For example, the specification:

- `5min=1000,#37;41` indicates that a 5 minute load average higher than 10 should be displayed with white characters on a red background.

A special tag named
`header` is used to control the color of the header for process display.  It should
be specified with no lower and upper limits, specifically `header=,#` followed by the ANSI color code.

You can see a list of color codes recognized by this installation of top
with the `-T` option.  This will also show the current set of tests used for
color highligting, as specified in the environment.

---

(end of man page extract)

### Colour Codes

The `color.h` file from the source code list the tags and codes the utility understands.  The tags are:

```
/*
 * These color tag names are currently in use
 * (or reserved for future use):
 *
 * cpu, size, res, time, 1min, 5min, 15min, host
 */
```

And the color are the ANSI ones:

```
/*
 * Valid ANSI values for colors are:
 *
 * 0    Reset all attributes
 * 1    Bright
 * 2    Dim
 * 4    Underscore  
 * 5    Blink
 * 7    Reverse
 * 8    Hidden
 * 
 *  Foreground Colours
 * 30   Black
 * 31   Red
 * 32   Green
 * 33   Yellow
 * 34   Blue
 * 35   Magenta
 * 36   Cyan
 * 37   White
 * 
 *  Background Colours
 * 40   Black
 * 41   Red
 * 42   Green
 * 43   Yellow
 * 44   Blue
 * 45   Magenta
 * 46   Cyan
 * 47   White
 */
```

### Example

Using the following setup, you can get a glimpse at the possibilities (here for top 3.8beta1 compiled on FreeBSD):

```
export TOPCOLORS="header=,#1\
:1min=,399#32:1min=400,799#33:1min=800,#31\
:5min=,299#32:5min=300,599#33:5min=600,#31\
:15min=,199#32:15min=200,399#33:15min=400,#31\
:cpu.user=,9#32:cpu.user=10,49#33:cpu.user=50,#31\
:cpu.system=,9#32:cpu.system=10,49#33:cpu.system=50,#31\
:cpu.interrupt=,9#32:cpu.interrupt=10,49#33:cpu.interrupt=50,#31"
```

A call to `top -T` will directly show you if top understands the color setup you've declared.  It will also list all the tags understood (which in my case where somewhat different from the content of the `color.h` file).

### Alternatives

On different UNIX systems, alternatives are used.  Under Linux you usually find the `top` utility coming from the [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package.  You can also install [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) which is a nice colourful alternative that is also available on [OSX](https://github.com/max-horvath/htop-osx) and FreeBSD (where it relies on the Linux layer), but AFAIK not on Solaris.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer and pertinant info that it is not supported in that version.
However, you have not actually given a complete example of a working TOPCOLORS value.
Imagine for a minute that a busy person hasn't got time to read this particular manual and wants simply to try out a couple of ready-made examples.

Comment: To be complete, I have added a TOPCOLORS working example.

Comment: Heh just noticed this, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but [I found this](http://www.pwrusr.com/system-administration/my-fav-top-color-scheme-and-command-options) `.toprc` that works with version 3.3.9 and later, which sets custom colors somewhere in there:

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> ```
> RCfile for "top with windows"           
> Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=3.000, Curwin=0
> Def     fieldscur=AEHIOQTWKNMbcdfgjplrsuvyzX
>         winflags=63800, sortindx=10, maxtasks=0
>         summclr=2, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
> Job     fieldscur=ABcefgjlrstuvyzMKNHIWOPQDX
>         winflags=62777, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0
>         summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
> Mem     fieldscur=ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX
>         winflags=62777, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
>         summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
> Usr     fieldscur=ABDECGfhijlopqrstuvyzMKNWX
>         winflags=62777, sortindx=4, maxtasks=0
>         summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Awesome example above. I tried something much simpler (albeit a little more attractive) on FreeBSD 10.1. I needed to install top 3.8 from source. The following works fomr csh/tcsh

```
    setenv TOPCOLORS "header=,#35;1:1min=,#31;1:5min=,#31;1:15min=,#31;1:cpu.user=,#32:cpu.system=,#32:cpu.nice=,#32:cpu.interrupt=,#32:cpu.idle=,#32:memory.wired=,#36:memory.active=,#36:memory.inact=,#36:memory.cache=,#36:memory.buf=,#36:memory.free=,#36:kernel.ctxsw=,#33:kernel.trap=,#33:kernel.intr=,#33:kernel.soft=,#33:kernel.fork=,#33:kernel.flt=,#33:kernel.pgin=,#33:kernel.pgout=,#33:kernel.fr=,#33:swap.total=,#34;1:swap.used=,#34;1:swap.free=,#34;1:swap.inuse=,#34;1:swap.in=,#34;1:swap.out=,#34;1"
```